# Return codes from payment-information webservice

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment, payment-methods, magento-2.0

For my custom method, I am calling PlaceOrder javascript function. It finally calls this URL:

/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

That calling returns "32". What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this number is the purchase order saved in database.